# indiviual files upload asp.net c#

Tags: c#

when i click on link button for adding more file upload then this add only 1 .. means 1 file upload which is already visible and 1 which is display on clicking on linkbutton ..

but when i click again on linkbutton for adding more then this not display ..

i try this

ok i do this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">upload</asp:LinkButton><br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit"  OnClick="Button1_Click" />
 </form>
```

suppose there is file upload control.. when we select file by clicking on browse and then click on upload then file name with extension i.e. abc.doc should be display  ... then when we use again same file upload and click on browse and select another file then file will be display i.e. xyz.pdf.. so there is two files  abc.doc and xyz.doc .. so this is want to do .. i want to upload files and display these uploaded files

**UPDATE**

for this i try this

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileuploadd(FileUpload1.FileName);

    }

    public void fileuploadd(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    SMSEntities s = new SMSEntities();
                    uploaded_file u = new uploaded_file();
                    {
                        u.fileupload = filename;


                    }
                    s.uploaded_file.Add(u);
                    s.SaveChanges();
                }
                //hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("upload") + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                Response.Write("<b>File: </b>" + hpf.FileName + " <b>Size:</b> " + hpf.ContentLength + " <b>Type:</b> " + hpf.ContentType + " Uploaded Successfully <br/>");


            }

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                       ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
               }
            }
            throw;
        }

    }
```

so when i select file and click on upload then file name is display .. but when i select again file and click on upload then 1st file name is disappear and 2nd file name is display where as i want both ..

so how i display both filenames ... and when click on submit then record files should be inserted in tables individually i am done with this but not with both filename display at a time ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a FileUpload Control on your .aspx like:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

then in your code behind:

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
   {
       foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
       {
           uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"),
           uploadedFile.FileName)); listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: this is not working.. and i want to upload files individually.,... i dont want to upload files multiples time at a time.

Comment: then you question is wrong, title said multiple fileuploads, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @superuser so basically you want to create more fileupload control dynamically? can you explain your idea more clearly please

Comment: no.. suppose there is file upload control.. when we select file by clicking on browse and then click on upload then file name with extension i.e. abc.doc should be display  ... then when we use again same file upload and click on browse and select another file then file will be display i.e. xyz.pdf.. so there is two files  abc.doc and xyz.doc .. so this is want to do .. i want to upload files and display these uploaded files

Comment: @superuser oh i see, does it postback after first file inserted into fileupload?

Comment: @superuser also tell me if you are using SQL? what ORM you are using? so i can give you a better code.

Comment: @superuser i think this question/answer completely help you out here stackoverflow.com/questions/41320243/how-to-save-an-image-database-and-display-it-on-a-panel-on-webpage/41320296#41320296

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple File Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTm1z.jpg)

HI Super User Previously I also had same Problem.
What i Actually did was I have Created 5 File Control's For Example 

1) FileUpload1 
2) FileUpload2
3) FileUpload3
4) FileUpload4
5) FileUpload5
 And I have 4 of them as Hidden on load.
On click of 1 st I am showing 2nd One and on click of 2nd I am showing the 3rd one and So on...

In the Controller/Method I am checking if the File Control is not null then proceeding with the normal File Upload Process By taking Array of File Uploads.

```
     <div id="flOther" runat="server">
    <div id="fileOtherUploadarea">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flOtherUPL" runat="server" />
    </div>
     <input style="width: 20px; border: 0px none; background-color:transparent;" id="btnOtherAddMoreFiles" type="button"     onclick="AddOtherMoreImages();" class="icon-plus-sign" />|
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOtherUpload" OnCommand="btnLnk_UploadOtherFiles" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")   %>   'runat="server">Upload Files</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function AddMoreImages() {
            if (!document.getElementById && !document.createElement)
                return false;
            var fileUploadarea = document.getElementById("fileUploadarea");
            if (!fileUploadarea)
                return false;
            var newLine = document.createElement("br");
            fileUploadarea.appendChild(newLine);
            var newFile = document.createElement("input");
            newFile.type = "file";
            newFile.setAttribute("class", "fileUpload");

            if (!AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId)
                AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId = 100;
            newFile.setAttribute("id", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
            newFile.setAttribute("name", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.appendChild(newFile);
            div.setAttribute("id", "div" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
            fileUploadarea.appendChild(div);
            AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId++;       }   

    </script>




protected void btnLnk_UploadOtherFiles(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {

    int ID;



    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument)))
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);
                    if (ValidExtesion(fileExtension))
                    {
                        int MaxSizeAllowed = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxFileSize"]);
                        if (hpf.ContentLength < MaxSizeAllowed)
                        {
                            int lastIndex = Convert.ToInt32(hpf.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                            string FileName = DateTime.Now.Millisecond + hpf.FileName.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
                            string FileName1 = hpf.FileName.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
                            FileName = FileName.Replace(" ", "");

                            StringBuilder AncTag = new StringBuilder();
                            AncTag = AncTag.Append("<a href='Attachments/AMT/'" + FileName + "' target='_blank'>'" + FileName1 + "' </a>");
                            string strAncTag = AncTag.ToString();
                            strAncTag = strAncTag.Replace("'", "");
                            hpf.SaveAs(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Attachments/AMT/" + FileName);
                            obj.UploadOtherFiles_ProblemDescription(ID, strAncTag);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog objER = new ErrorLog(ex);
    }
    finally
    {

        obj = null;
        grdPDC.EditIndex = -1;

    }

}
```